# Is UML also the correct method of representing document-oriented ddbb architecture?

Tags: database, non-relational-database

I have seen and studied the approach for SQL and relational models with UML, but not a clue about non-relational document data base modeling.

I am actually designing a MongoDB database for a college project and I do not know how to properly present it. Should I also use the classic relational model or there's another way to do it?

Comment: *Best approach* and *advice* are both opinion-based, and *Any docs* is a request for an off-site resource. You'll find you have much better experiences here if you spend some time reading the [help] pages to learn what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before posting.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will edit my question.